# Dummit and Foote 4.2 Corollary 5. Group action

Tags: abstract-algebra, normal-subgroups

Corollary 5: G is finite group of order $n$ and $p$ smallest prime divides $n$ then any subgroup of index $p$ is normal.

The book begins with let $H\leq G$ s.t. $|G:H|=p$ then let $K$ be the kernel of the action of G on the left cosets of H (action is left multiplication ) now it is clear that $G/H$ isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_p$ but why $G/K$ is also isomorphic to a subgroup of the same symmetric group. That's the question.

Comment: Since you don't start out assuming $H$ is normal, it doesn't make sense to say $G/H$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_p$ since we don't yet know $G/H$ is even a group! The action is a group homorphism $G\to\mathrm{Perm}(G/H)$, and by the isomorphism theorem this means $G/K$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $\mathrm{Perm}(G/H)$, where $K$ is the kernel.

Comment: G/K is a subgroup of G, say of order $d$. $d$ must divide $p$ since Perm(G,H) has order p. But that implies there is a prime $q$ smaller than $p$ which divides $n$, the order of G.

Comment: Can someone add this as an answer so I can accept it thanks.

Comment: Aha I see so $Perm(G/H)$ is a group with $p!$ elements since we have $p$ different cosets hence the number of possible permutations is $p!$? The map is defined by if we consider the different cosetes as $\{g_1H , g_2H , g_3H \cdots g_pH \}=\{1,2,3,\cdots p\}$ then we check where $g\in G $ permutes the cosets thats the map and we can have all different permutations $S_p$ then $G/K \cong M$ a subgroup of $S_p$. Right?